# How to find the mismatch rows in sql - postgresl?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables. I want to find the mismatch row

```
Input 
Table name: sale_order

header_id      name   date_col                        total_amt
45             apple  2021-01-26 19:55:33.350589      100
32             grape  2021-01-27 19:55:33.350589      200
22             plums  2021-01-27 17:55:33.350589      250
30             lemon  2021-01-28 19:55:33.350589      400

Table name: bill_order

id   product_id   date_col                        total_amt
1    45           2021-01-26 19:55:33.350589      200
2    32           2021-01-27 19:55:33.350589      200
3    22           2021-01-27 17:55:33.350589      500
4    30           2021-01-28 19:55:33.350589      400
```

Output: Mismatch (Wrong values in total_amt)

```
select  sale_order.header_id ,sale_order.total_amt,bill_order.total_amt 
FROM sale_order
INNER JOIN bill_order ON sale_order.total_amt != bill_order.total_amt` and 
   header_id = product_id
```

Expected Output:

```
  header_id  total_amt  total_amt
  45         100        200
  22         250        500
```

I want to find the mismatch total_amt.
And want to display
I want to find the mismatch total_amt.
And want to display

I want to find the mismatch total_amt.
And want to display

Comment: It is highly suspicious to me that `header_id` in one table would match something called `product_id` in another table.  Are you sure you question correctly reflects the data model?  Also, do you care if something is missing from one of the tables?

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.header_id, a.total_amt, b.total_amt 
from sale_order a 
inner join bill_order b on 
    a.header_id = b.product_id 
where a.total_amt != b.total_amt;
```

Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use aliases for recognize columns with same title from different tables:

```
select  
    sale_order.header_id,
    sale_order.total_amt sale_amt, 
    bill_order.total_amt bill_amt
from sale_order
join bill_order ON 
    sale_order.total_amt != bill_order.total_amt and 
    header_id = product_id
   ;
```

Result:

```
+===========+==========+==========+
| header_id | sale_amt | bill_amt |
+===========+==========+==========+
| 45        | 100      | 200      |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| 22        | 250      | 500      |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

[share SQL query](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2719062a1136166c56771499858d6369&php_version=null&sql_version=psql11)